# How to Configure nsswitch.conf in ubuntu 18.04 (upgrading from 16.04)

Tags: 18.04, client, nis

I am upgrading my client system from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04

> ## /etc/nsswitch.conf
>
> passwd:         compat files nis nisplus
>
> group:          compat files nis nisplus
>
> shadow:         compat files nis nisplus
>
> gshadow:        files
>
> hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
>
> networks:       files
>
> protocols:      db files
>
> services:       db files
>
> ethers:         db files
>
> rpc:            db files
>
> netgroup:       nis

In ubuntu 18.04

> ## /etc/nsswitch.conf
>
> passwd:         compat files nis nisplus systemd
>
> group:          compat files nis nisplus systemd
>
> shadow:         compat files nis nisplus
>
> gshadow:        files
>
> hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
>
> networks:       files
>
> protocols:      db files
>
> services:       db files
>
> ethers:         db files
>
> rpc:            db files
>
> netgroup:       nis

But now I am unable to connect to server.

I am getting the message:

A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I run nis ( dont have nisplus) and I check local accounts first then nis.
I found that compat will do the necessary with nis checking for me( perhaps nisplus as well)ie checks the + entries in /etc/passwd  and check local passwd with + and override home directories shells etc.
If use it in this way, I can log in from command line with both a local and nis account ( with both a local and nfs home). For some reason there is a delay of 25 seconds approximately until the shell prompt is returned. On X it times out and locks screen. So I still have difficulties, but this might point you a bit further down the road or maybe it will work for you. Id be interested if you could post if you get it working fully.

/etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd: files compat  systemd

group: files compat  systemd

shadow: files compat 
gshadow: files

hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname

networks: files

protocols: db files

services: db files

ethers: db files

rpc: db files

netgroup: nis